# Microsoft won't let me login with my Hotmail account

Tags: onedrive

All of a sudden, a OneDrive dialog box appeared on my desktop telling me that it failed to login with my Hotmail account. I tried logging in again but it showed the same message that it couldn't login. I tried to login on https://hotmail.com, and it shows my account does not exist. After many attempts, it shows "Connection Error" and goes back to the login page without any error message. It is not my connection issue because it happened on multiple devices. It has happened to my secondary account as well.

Is Microsoft being hacked right now?

Comment: Unlikely. Your Account might've been compromised, that's more likely. Especially depending on how and where you use your address and what kind of complexity your password has.

Comment: My account isn't hacked. I would get an sms if something changed. It is happen on my secondary account too

Comment: OneDrive is probably down at the moment.  Give it some time and try again later today.

Comment: For me the same. B.T.W. hotmail.com doesn't exist anymore. It's outlook.com. I also can't login with my hotmail account on outlook.com (which I always could). So I think it's temporarily down.

Comment: We are not alone :) http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/outlook-com-outage.233744/ and https://www.google.nl/search?q=outlook.com+outage#q=outlook.com+outage&safe=off&tbs=qdr:h&* (set period in tools for one hour)

Comment: http://news.softpedia.com/news/microsoft-services-go-down-skype-xbox-onedrive-all-affected-513649.shtml

Comment: @Rik: Perhaps you should write that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'll write this as an answer but I think it's best to delete the question after today because this is a temporary issue. (but not before the issue is resolved, otherwise we get new questions about this again.)

When dealing with a problem in service it's best to Google if others have the same issue. You can enter the keywords `outlook outage` in Google and press the `Tools`-button. After that choose `One hour` from the period-pulldown. Now you get only the Google-pages from the last hour with the same keywords (and probably the same problems).

At the moment Microsoft services seems to have login issues with Microsoft Accounts (at least with the @hotmail.com and probably others too). Please be patient. I'm sure Microsoft is working hard to solve the issue.

Comment: "I'll write this as an answer but I think it's best to delete the question after today because this is a temporary issue." - This is a great reason to vote to close the question, then all other questions, can be pointed to this first question similar to how the Epson printer Google Print questions were handled.

Comment: F.Y.I. for outlook.com the sign-in issue is already resolved.